# how to solve "Warning: file_get_contents() error" message - contact form?

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

When I click the button "Send" on my **unfilled** contact form , my javascript validation messages show up and then I get error message:

**Full error message:**

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in mail.php on line 19
mail send ... OK
```

**What happens after:**

I receive an empty email with the attached file "Part 2.bin"

**What I want to happen**

If I try to "SEND" unfiled contact form, I want my javascript validation to show up and prevent the  contact form being submited until all required fields are filled.

**I have tried doing this instead:**

```
<form  name="contactForm"  action="php/mail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

`onsubmit="validateForm(); return false;"` instead of `onsubmit="return validateForm()"`

**What happens**
Contact form validations messages show up but another issue occur

**Another issue:** When i try to submit fully filed contact form , it's not submiting... (no error messages..)

Im very new to PHP and Javascript, Its been 3 days since I got stuck on this issue... Someone please save me

```js
// Defining a function to display error message
function printError(elemId, hintMsg) {
    document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = hintMsg;
}

// Defining a function to validate form 
function validateForm() {
    // Retrieving the values of form elements 
    let name = document.contactForm.name.value;
    let email = document.contactForm.email.value;
    let country = document.contactForm.country.value;
    let subject = document.contactForm.subject.value;

    
    // Defining error variables with a default value
    let nameValidation = emailValidation = countryValidation = subjectValidation;
    
    // Validate name
    if(name == "") {
        printError("nameValidation", "Please enter your name");
    } else {
        let regex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;                
        if(regex.test(name) === false) {
            printError("nameValidation", "Please enter a valid name");
        } else {
            printError("nameValidation", "");
            nameValidation = false;
        }
    }
    
    // Validate email address
    if(email == "") {
        printError("emailValidation", "Please enter your email address");
    } else {
        // Regular expression for basic email validation
        let regex = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/;
        if(regex.test(email) === false) {
            printError("emailValidation", "Please enter a valid email address");
        } else{
            printError("emailValidation", "");
            emailValidation = false;
        }
    }
    
  
    // Validate country
    if(country == "Select") {
        printError("countryValidation", "Please select your country");
    } else {
        printError("countryValidation", "");
        countryValidation = false;
    }
  
   // Validate subject
    if(subject == "Select") {
        printError("subjectValidation", "Please select the subject");
    } else {
        printError("subjectValidation", "");
        subjectValidation = false;
    }
    
 
    
    // Prevent the form from being submitted if there are any errors
    if((nameValidation || emailValidation || countryValidation || subjectValidation) == true) {
       return false;
    } else {
        // Creating a string from input data for preview
        let dataPreview = "You've entered the following details: \n" +
                          "Full Name: " + name + "\n" +
                          "Email Address: " + email + "\n" +                          
                          "Country: " + country + "\n" +
                          "Subject: " + subject + "\n"; 
        // if(hobbies.length) {
        //     dataPreview += "Hobbies: " + hobbies.join(", ");
        // }
        // Display input data in a dialog box before submitting the form
        // alert(dataPreview);
    }
};
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="/js/contact-form-validation.js" ></script>
    
    <style>
    body {  width: 100%;  height: 100vh;  display: flex;  justify-content: center;  align-items: center;  background-color: aquamarine; }section {  width: 300px; }form {  display: flex;  flex-direction: column;  background-color: #f2f2f2;  padding: 3rem 1rem; }input, select {  margin-bottom: 1rem; }label {  font-weight: bold; }  .validation-message {    color: red;    font-size: 90%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section>
     
    <form  name="contactForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="confirmation.php" method="post">
        <!-- name -->
        <label for="name">Full name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your full name.."  />
        <div class="validation-message" id="nameValidation"></div>
        <!-- email -->
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail.."  />
        <div class="validation-message" id="emailValidation"></div>
        <!-- country -->
        <label for="country">Country</label>
        <select id="country" name="country" >
            <option>Select</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
            <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
            <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select>
        <div class="validation-message" id="countryValidation"></div>
        <!-- subject -->
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <select id="subject" name="subject" >
            <option>Select</option>
            <option value="Media Enquiries">Media Enquiries</option>
            <option value="Donation Enquiries">Donation Enquiries</option>
            <option value="Volunteering Enquiries">Volunteering Enquiries</option>
            <option value="Collaboration Enquiries">Collaboration Enquiries</option>
            <option value="Reporting Scams">Reporting Scams</option>
            <option value="Other">Other.. (Specify in the message field )</option>
        </select>
        <div class="validation-message" id="subjectValidation"></div>
        <!-- attach file -->
        <label style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px;" for="message">docx and pdf formats</label>
        <input type="file" id="attachment-file" name="file">
        
        <!-- message text area -->
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write your message here.."
            style="height:100px"></textarea>
        <!--  send button-->
           <input type="submit" id="send-button" name="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

**mail.php**

```
<?php
    $userAttachment =  $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $userAttachmentName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
    $userName = $_POST['name'];
    $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $userCountry = $_POST['country'];
    $userSubject = $_POST['subject'];
    $userMessage = $_POST['message'];     
    $message ="\r\n  Name: ". $userName . "\r\n  Email: " . $userEmail . "\r\n  Country: " . $userCountry . "\r\n  Subject: " . $userSubject . "\r\n\r\n  Message: \r\n\r\n  " . $userMessage; 
    $subject = "[ ".$userSubject." ]"." from ". "[ ".$userCountry." ]";
    $fromname = "Contact Form";
    $fromemail = 'autoreply@email.com';  //if u dont have an email create one on your cpanel
    $mailto = 'example@example.com';  //the email which u want to recv this email
 **(THIS IS LINE 19) -->**   $content = file_get_contents($userAttachmentName);  
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());
    // carriage return type (RFC)
    $eol = "\r\n";
    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">" . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;
    // message
    $body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;
    // attachment
    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $userAttachment . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
    $body .= $content . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";
    //SEND Mail
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // do what you want after sending the email
        
        
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
        print_r( error_get_last() );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The return false will stop the submission.

You NEED the multipart to get the file

Try this

```
<form  name="contactForm"  action="php/mail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

You need to define the validations with a default value - now you just define them with null

```
let nameValidation = emailValidation = countryValidation = subjectValidation = true;
```

Then you need to set them to false everywhere you call the error, NOT in the else

```
 printError("nameValidation", "Please enter your name");
 nameValidation = false;
```

and change the validateForm function to return false when not ok, true when ok:

```
return emailValidation && countryValidation && subjectValidation;
```

at the very end of the function

Code:

```js
// Defining a function to display error message
function printError(elemId, hintMsg) {
  document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = hintMsg;
}

// Defining a function to validate form 
document.getElementById("contactForm").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  // Retrieving the values of form elements 
  let fullname = this.fullname.value;
  let email = this.email.value;
  let country = this.country.value;
  let subject = this.subject.value;


  // Defining error variables with a default value
  let nameValidation = emailValidation = countryValidation = subjectValidation = true;


  // Validate name
  printError("nameValidation", "");
  if (fullname == "") {
    printError("nameValidation", "Please enter your name");
    nameValidation = false;
  } else {
    let regex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
    if (regex.test(fullname) === false) {
      printError("nameValidation", "Please enter a valid name");
      nameValidation = false;
    }
  }

  // Validate email address
  printError("emailValidation", "");
  if (email == "") {
    printError("emailValidation", "Please enter your email address");
    emailValidation = false;
  } else {
    // Regular expression for basic email validation
    let regex = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/;
    if (regex.test(email) === false) {
      printError("emailValidation", "Please enter a valid email address");
      emailValidation = false;
    }
  }

  // Validate country
  printError("countryValidation", "");
  if (country == "Select") {
    printError("countryValidation", "Please select your country");
    countryValidation = false;
  }



  // Validate subject
  printError("subjectValidation", "");
  if (subject == "Select") {
    printError("subjectValidation", "Please select the subject");
    subjectValidation = false;
  }



  // Prevent the form from being submitted if there are any errors
  if (!nameValidation || !emailValidation || !countryValidation || !subjectValidation) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    return false;
  }
  // Creating a string from input data for preview
  let dataPreview = "You've entered the following details: \n" +
    "Full Name: " + fullname + "\n" +
    "Email Address: " + email + "\n" +
    "Country: " + country + "\n" +
    "Subject: " + subject + "\nSubmit?";
  if (!confirm(dataPreview)) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Contact Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <script src="/js/contact-form-validation.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: aquamarine;
    }
    
    section {
      width: 300px;
    }
    
    form {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 3rem 1rem;
    }
    
    input,
    select {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    
    label {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .validation-message {
      color: red;
      font-size: 90%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <section>

    <form id="contactForm" action="confirmation.php" method="post">
      <!-- name -->
      <label for="name">Full name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Your full name.." />
      <div class="validation-message" id="nameValidation"></div>
      <!-- email -->
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail.." />
      <div class="validation-message" id="emailValidation"></div>
      <!-- country -->
      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <select id="country" name="country">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
      </select>
      <div class="validation-message" id="countryValidation"></div>
      <!-- subject -->
      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      <select id="subject" name="subject">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="Media Enquiries">Media Enquiries</option>
        <option value="Donation Enquiries">Donation Enquiries</option>
        <option value="Volunteering Enquiries">Volunteering Enquiries</option>
        <option value="Collaboration Enquiries">Collaboration Enquiries</option>
        <option value="Reporting Scams">Reporting Scams</option>
        <option value="Other">Other.. (Specify in the message field )</option>
      </select>
      <div class="validation-message" id="subjectValidation"></div>
      <!-- attach file -->
      <label style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px;" for="message">docx and pdf formats</label>
      <input type="file" id="attachment-file" name="file">

      <!-- message text area -->
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write your message here.." style="height:100px"></textarea>
      <!--  send button-->
      <input type="submit" id="send-button" value="Send" />
    </form>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you please read the question again.
I have tried this already

Comment: No you haven't. I read your question. You a) did not initialise the validation booleans and b) did not return the OR'ed collection of validations to only submit if all three were ok

Comment: Ah, you also need to MOVE the validation to after the print

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will let you know in a minute if it's solved.

Comment: not sure I understant last bit:
and change the validateForm function to return false when not ok, true when ok:
`return emailValidation && countryValidation && subjectValidation;`
at the very end of the function

Do I just add the `return emailValidation && countryValidation && subjectValidation;` just before }; of the ValidFrom function?

Comment: @PaulC Have a look at the full and simplified code. Also I changed from name to fullname so `$userName = $_POST['fullname'];` . and removed the name="submit" from the submit button.

Comment: I saw you reverse the logic and emailValidation=false means it was ok. That is hard on my eyes so I actually reversed the tests. Please see how I use the addEventListener and e.preventDefault to stop submission

Comment: I updated the code with fullname in the regex too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233747/discussion-between-paul-c-and-mplungjan).

Comment: @ mplungjan Thanks for the answers, but your code only works offline.. 
When I try to upload it on the server, validation doesn't work and I get this error message :  
Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in `php/mail.php on line 19
mail send ... OK`

Comment: That is not a JS issue